# Python Codecs Unicode Decode Error

Tags: python, file-io, unicode, utf-8

I was using the codecs module for reading a text file and extracting information from it. My code is as follows:

```
import codecs
handle = codecs.open('try.txt',encoding="utf-8")
f1 = handle.read()
# Do further stuff with f1
```

However, it is giving me the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 628: invalid continuation byte
```

Can anybody help me on this? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Your input file is not valid UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Is there a way to get through that? I need the utf-8 encoded version of the file for further processing. Or equivalently, should I use another encoding?

Comment: Either your data is corrupted (you'll have to try and decode up to the corrupted part, then start decoding past it again; UTF-8's nature does allow you to scan for the next valid byte), or you picked the wrong codec. How certain are you about what encoding has been used for this file?

Comment: "I need the utf-8 encoded version of the file for further processing" -- do you mean you want to convert **to** UTF-8, not **from**?